# CMPedometerData->averageActivePace is 0 in iphone 5s

Tags: ios, iphone, core-motion

```
[cmPedometer queryPedometerDataFromDate:startDate1 toDate:endDate1 withHandler:^(CMPedometerData * _Nullable pedoData, NSError * _Nullable error) {
{
    if(error!=nil)
    {
        SH_DDLogError(TAG_SHTCoreMotionManager, @"[ERR] getStepDataFromStartTime %@", error);
    }
    else if(pedoData.numberOfSteps != nil && [pedoData.numberOfSteps intValue]> 0)
    {
        // Issue - pedoData.averageActivePace is ZERO in iphone 5s
    }
```

This is happening in couple all the iPhone 5s phones we have checked so far. We also tested in latest iOS version 10.3.

Has anyone faced similar problem or know how to resolve it?

Comment: In iPhone 6/7 it is working fine BTW.

Comment: I am using iPhone 5s where it is available. Besides, I am getting step count and distance, but averageActivePace is 0. That is the issue.